# Geo Nodes - How to instance curve caps with correct rotation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I've been trying to figure out how to instance meshes at the endpoints of a curve via Geo Nodes. There are tutorials for Pipes but when using something with a complex shape, the rotation of the instanced object goes crazy.

The same goes when using the *Resample Curve* node.

How is the Rotation date beeing transferred when using it?

There should be a way to compare the resampled points on the curve with the vertices of the profiled curves.

[image]

The Blend File:

https://pasteall.org/blend/50f4984700014eb79511ad0971d40e9f

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, only one node is missing.

You trimmed the curve here with `Trim Curve`, which is correct, but if you want to instantiate a profile at the endpoints, you somehow need the rotation of the endpoints.

And the easiest way to achieve this is to send your trimmed curve to the node `Curve to Points`, reducing it to two points (the start and end points).

This node also returns the rotation of the points, which you can then use directly in the instantiation.

[image]