# Custom caps for curve to mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create tubes using geometry nodes. I want to use different materials for the caps and the sides. I reduced it to a solid strand while i solve my rotation issue.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to rotate the end caps.

Here is an attempt using "sample curve" for the cap positions. I have also tried "instance on points" with "select endpoints" with a similar result.

[image: Attempt using sample curve]

[image: Result]

Comment: If you Instances on Points and use an Align Euler to Vector with a Curve Tangent connected into the vector socket it should work  (Z axis).

Comment: Works! Alignment axis: Z, Pivot: Auto, Factor: 1.0. @Vagabonk You want to make it an answer?

Comment: Hi, John! Glad you've got a fix! .. (BTW, don't forget to flip one end.) This question might be clobbered, though, as a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/243389/35559 .. would that be fair?

Comment: @RobinBetts I looked at that before posting. Thought it was different with the spherical ends.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254598/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286437/

Comment: Yeah... This is a duplicate alright. Sorry.

Comment: @John ...a duplicate of which existing question/answer?

Comment: @quellenform This is pretty spot on: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286437/extruding-a-filled-face-with-a-hole-in-it-along-a-curve-using-geometry-nodes