Rounded Caps for Blender Geo Node Hair Curves?
I am trying to recreate this cloth.

And have used the set hair profile geo nodes to achieve this till now:

I just want to add rounded caps to the end of the strands so they look like the cloth above and I can proceed with the rest of the scene. I tried making round caps in blender following some tutorials but to implement it for every single strand is above my current geo nodes understanding. I appreciate all the help and energy for helping me solve this. Thanks

After following quellenform's advice, I've come this close:



I don't think there is a simple way. You could add half of a sphere at the end of each hair. With the correct orientation and resolution, you could merge it into one hair mesh. That being said, I've never used hair with geometry nodes.

Try the following: Curve to Points (Count:2) > Instance on Points (with Rotation of Curve to Points and a hemisphere as Instance). Also helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254598/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309859/

@quellenform Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, I've got very close, but the sphere caps and the tubes are not matching together, i.e their radius are a bit off. Can you please help me with that?

Do you use Cycles or Eevee to render? The 2nd screenshot looks like Cycles because of the rounded ribbons.

Look at the screenshot of your nodetree: there is an error message on the Curve to Mesh node. I guess it is because you instance spheres on the points - a sphere is a mesh object and not a suitable input for the Curve to Mesh node. You have to use the Join Geometry node after converting the curve to a mesh. Apart from that, I guess there are some discrepancies between the radii so they differ in the end. But I cannot check it because the file in your question does not have the nodetree shown in the screenshot.

@GordonBrinkmann Hi, just updated the file, yes I just made the changes now after seeing this. Please help me with the radii, I tried using a same value node but I don't know where to put it so the strands are also the same radii as the spheres
